# Getting a list of Contacts on SenseUI 2.1?

Tags: android

This is simple enough on every other version of Android, including SenseUI 1.5.

```
//For Contacts
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
this.startActivityForResult(pickIntent, RESULT);

//For Phones
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phones.CONTENT_URI);
this.startActivityForResult(pickIntent, RESULT);
```

On SenseUI 2.1 (HTC Incredible) this shows a list of numbers (the URI number).  So you get a list of 1-200 if you have 200 contacts.  Selecting one of the contacts you can then gather all of the information needed.

Is there any good work around known?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have any solution for this issue, which also occurs on the HTC Desire, but would recommend to file a bug with HTC instead of figuring out workarounds, as this IMHO clearly is a bug in HTC's implementation.